# iOS View Controller Stops Rotating

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uicontainerview

I have a View Controller that displays some basic information. When an action occurs, I have a full screen container view that I fade in. That container view has a different View Controller that handles events in the view.

After another action, specifically a rotation, another full screen container view is faded in, but in that situation, it fades out after a few seconds.

Everything is working great, but after a few rotations, the container view's controllers stop receiving did/will rotate events (including the initial view controller that the container views are over). And, the view's stop rotating altogether. Leaving the app and putting it into background mode and opening it again fixes it temporarily.

I've been stuck on this for days, and am not sure why this would happen. Is iOS unloading the initial view controller for some reason? How do I prevent this or make one of the other View Controllers the main one?

Comment: Please, show the code so that we can help

Comment: Well, most of the embedding is done in Storyboard, I'm not even sure where to begin with the code as it is a large project.

Comment: what do u mean by rotation ? is it an animation ?>

Comment: show your view will appear and view did appear code

Comment: When it rotates, the third view appears (it has a separate view controller).

Comment: And there is no view will appear or did appear code

Comment: Initially, I thought I set up the child view controllers incorrectly, but what's strange is I receive rotation events for a random number of rotations (first view controller receives, then the second, and the third). But that eventually stops and zero of them receive it.

Comment: I should also say, I have a gesture recognizer on the second view controller (first container view), that eventually stops working when rotations stop being received